# angular/electron app don't show video mp4 when app is in distribution with .exe

Tags: angular, electron, electron-builder

Hello I have make a simple electron app start from angular 7 app and after install electron , my app show in background a video that loop and   in localhost i show the video start and loop , but when i build and make a distribution pack for windows and i start the exe file i show only a picture of a video , and this dont start.

**slider.component.html**

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="col-md 12">

       <video  autoplay  loop poster=""  id="bgvid"  #videoPlayer>
                  <!-- MP4 must be first for iPad! -->
                  <source src=" ./assets/video/Superb_sunset.mp4" type="video/mp4" /><!-- Safari / iOS video    -->


              </video>
              </div>
</div>
```

**main.js**

```
 const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

let win;

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 600, 
    height: 600,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    icon: `file://${__dirname}/dist/lasalute/assets/logo.png`
  })


  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/lasalute/index.html`)

  //// uncomment below to open the DevTools.
  // win.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Event when the window is closed.
  win.on('closed', function () {
    win = null
  })
}

// Create window on electron intialization
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {

  // On macOS specific close process
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  // macOS specific close process
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

**folder organization**

```
-dist

  --lasalute(project name )

   --- assets

   --- index.html

   ---main

   ---style.css

   ---other

-lasalute_win32(in this folder there is a .exe )

-src

 --app

     ---slider.component.html

     ---slider.component.css

     ---slider.component.ts

 --assets

     ---img

     ---video

        ----superb_sunset.mp4

 --index.html

-main.js
```

Comment: have you tried using the absolute path of ` ./assets/video/Superb_sunset.mp4"`?

Comment: yes I have tried this but in distrbution mode i see only  a screen of video

Comment: have you trield using `file://with_absolute_path` ?

Comment: I tried now, inserting this path src =  '     "file: // C: \ Users \ danie_000 \ Desktop \ lasalute \ lasalute \ src \ assets \ video \ Superb_sunset.mp4" '      in the browser in localhost angular I do not see nullla, but when I call electron always in debug mode I see only a still image of the video, and same thing if I do  'electron-packager.   --platform = win32' to create the distribution I still see a still image of the video